# Sorting a string of full names alphabetically by last names and displaying it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Today with the help of my mentor and some tutorials online we came up with this but I still don't know how to display it in HTML

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  const aName = a.split(" ");
  const bName = b.split(" ");
  const aLastName = aName[aName.length - 1];
  const bLastName = bName[bName.length - 1];
  if (aLastName < bLastName) return -1;
  if (aLastName > bLastName) return 1;
  return 0;
}
const fullNames = "John Mats,Braxton Jackson,Joe Lang,Andre Torrealba,Jonathan Morales";
console.log(fullNames);
const fullNamesArray = fullNames.split(",");
console.log(fullNamesArray);
fullNamesArray.sort(compare);
document.getElementById(nameList).innerHTML = fullNamesArray();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ol id=#nameList></ol>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I know this is probably a homework project, but in the real world, you don’t want to make any assumptions about how to split a full name into first and last name. There’s some people whose first name is multiple words and some people whose last name is multiple words. The best solution is to ask someone what their first name and last name are, and store them separately. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at end of **javascript**:

```
for(var i = 0;i < fullNamesArray.length;i++)
{
document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML += "<li>" + fullNamesArray[i] + "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method, It will iterate and add the list tag for each value and it will be assigned
v

```
ar str = '<ul>'

fullNamesArray.forEach(function(f) {
  str += '<li>'+ f + '</li>';
}); 

str += '</ul>';
document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your array elements inside `li` tag and then push into `ul` tag. Try below code may be this is what you want.

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  const aName = a.split(" ");
  const bName = b.split(" ");
  const aLastName = aName[aName.length - 1];
  const bLastName = bName[bName.length - 1];
  if (aLastName < bLastName) return -1;
  if (aLastName > bLastName) return 1;
  return 0;
}
var liHtml = "";
const fullNames = "John Mats,Braxton Jackson,Joe Lang,Andre Torrealba,Jonathan Morales";
const fullNamesArray = fullNames.split(",");
fullNamesArray.sort(compare);
fullNamesArray.forEach(function(f) {
  liHtml += '<li>'+ f + '</li>';
}); 
document.getElementById('#nameList').innerHTML = liHtml;
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ol id=#nameList></ol>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```